# (Bluez) How to get bluetooth headset buttons input?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez, gatt

I have a bluetooth headset connected to a linux device.
I would like to programmatically receive the play/pause/next/previous/volUp/volDown button press.

After some research I found out that I can interact with Bluez with dbus.
I tried to register a MediaPlayer using this script https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/test/example-player
But when I inspect dbus there's no new player, and it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

I also tried to use the Gatt services, but I can't find org.bluez.GattService1 anywhere.

What would be the best way to get the inputs? Is there something wrong with my Bluez?

Background:
My goal is to have a audio input and audio output both connected via bluetooth to a rpi.
I did manage to do this and have the sound from the input play on the output.
Now I would like to forward the inputs too.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked into this a bit and discovered some things but not reached a full conclusion. I thought I would share it here in the hope that someone can edit/improve the answer.

I have connected up a Bluetooth headset to my Raspberry Pi and DBus interfaces of interest seem to be `org.bluez.MediaControl1` and `org.bluez.MediaTransport1`

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ busctl tree 'org.bluez'
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    ├─/org/bluez/hci0
    │ ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95
    │ │ └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95/fd2
    └─/org/bluez/test

(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ busctl introspect 'org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95'
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
org.bluez.Device1                   interface -         -                                        -
.CancelPairing                      method    -         -                                        -
.Connect                            method    -         -                                        -
.ConnectProfile                     method    s         -                                        -
.Disconnect                         method    -         -                                        -
.DisconnectProfile                  method    s         -                                        -
.Pair                               method    -         -                                        -
.Adapter                            property  o         "/org/bluez/hci0"                        emits-change
.Address                            property  s         "74:5C:4B:F8:6D:95"                      emits-change
.AddressType                        property  s         "public"                                 emits-change
.AdvertisingData                    property  a{yv}     -                                        emits-change
.AdvertisingFlags                   property  ay        -                                        emits-change
.Alias                              property  s         "Jabra Move SE v1.0.0"                   emits-change writable
.Appearance                         property  q         -                                        emits-change
.Blocked                            property  b         false                                    emits-change writable
.Class                              property  u         2360324                                  emits-change
.Connected                          property  b         true                                     emits-change
.Icon                               property  s         "audio-card"                             emits-change
.LegacyPairing                      property  b         false                                    emits-change
.ManufacturerData                   property  a{qv}     -                                        emits-change
.Modalias                           property  s         -                                        emits-change
.Name                               property  s         "Jabra Move SE v1.0.0"                   emits-change
.Paired                             property  b         true                                     emits-change
.RSSI                               property  n         -                                        emits-change
.ServiceData                        property  a{sv}     -                                        emits-change
.ServicesResolved                   property  b         true                                     emits-change
.Trusted                            property  b         false                                    emits-change writable
.TxPower                            property  n         -                                        emits-change
.UUIDs                              property  as        5 "00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb… emits-change
org.bluez.MediaControl1             interface -         -                                        -
.FastForward                        method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Next                               method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Pause                              method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Play                               method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Previous                           method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Rewind                             method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Stop                               method    -         -                                        deprecated
.VolumeDown                         method    -         -                                        deprecated
.VolumeUp                           method    -         -                                        deprecated
.Connected                          property  b         true                                     emits-change
.Player                             property  o         -                                        emits-change
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                                        -
.Introspect                         method    -         s                                        -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                                        -
.Get                                method    ss        v                                        -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                                    -
.Set                                method    ssv       -                                        -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                                        -

(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ busctl introspect 'org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95/fd2'
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                            FLAGS
org.bluez.MediaTransport1           interface -         -                                       -
.Acquire                            method    -         hqq                                     -
.Release                            method    -         -                                       -
.TryAcquire                         method    -         hqq                                     -
.Codec                              property  y         0                                       emits-change
.Configuration                      property  ay        4 17 21 2 51                            emits-change
.Delay                              property  q         -                                       emits-change
.Device                             property  o         "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95" emits-change
.State                              property  s         "idle"                                  emits-change
.UUID                               property  s         "0000110A-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"  emits-change
.Volume                             property  q         -                                       emits-change writ
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                                       -
.Introspect                         method    -         s                                       -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                                       -
.Get                                method    ss        v                                       -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                                   -
.Set                                method    ssv       -                                       -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                                       -
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

The `org.bluez.MediaControl1` has deprecated next to it and `org.bluez.MediaTransport1` is documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/media-api.txt#n587

`org.bluez.MediaTransport1` has a volume property, but when I try to read it there is an error:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ busctl get-property 'org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95/fd2' 'org.bluez.MediaTransport1' Volume
No such property 'Volume'
```

But I can read other properties fine:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ busctl get-property 'org.bluez' '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_5C_4B_F8_6D_95/fd2' 'org.bluez.MediaTransport1' State
s "active"
```

I have been using this bit of code to hold it in the `Active` state while I introspect the interfaces.

```py
import os
from gi.repository import GLib
from pydbus import SystemBus
from time import sleep

dev_addr = '74:5C:4B:F8:6D:95'

bluez_service = 'org.bluez'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{adapter_path}/dev_{dev_addr.replace(':', '_')}"

bus = SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get(bluez_service, '/')
adapter = bus.get(bluez_service, adapter_path)

def get_media_transport_path(dev_path):
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for dev_objs in mng_objs:
        if dev_objs.startswith(dev_path):
            state = mng_objs[dev_objs].get('org.bluez.MediaTransport1', {}).get('State', False)
            print('State', state)
            if state:
                return dev_objs

mt_path = get_media_transport_path(device_path)
mt = bus.get(bluez_service, mt_path)
mt_data = mt.Acquire()
print('Acquire', mt_data)
print('GetAll', mt.GetAll('org.bluez.MediaTransport1'))
print('Transport Device', mt.Device)
print('Transport state', mt.State)

sleep(20)
mt.Release()
print('Transport State', mt.State)
```

My next investigation was going to be around the File Descriptor returned by `Acquire` however my DBus library of choice has an issue around fd's  https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/pull/86

Comment: I too face the same issue and I couldn't get Volume property which I hope can give the current "hardware" volume level on my sony wf-1000xm3. :( Have you made any progress so far?

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but the Arch Linux Wiki provides good instructions for this:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Configuration_via_CLI

Install `bluez-utils` and run `mpris-proxy`. This will forward the commands to the mpris2 interface, where it can be picked up by your media player.